# Round robin with gender split

Tags: php, round-robin

How to make round robin with 2 arrays

```
$male = array('peter','john');
$female = array('anna','susan');
```

Where eg. peter can't talk with john. Only with girls.
Here is my working round robin code but only for 1 array

```
function roundRobin( array $teams ){

        if (count($teams)%2 != 0){
            array_push($teams,"hold");
        }
        $away = array_splice($teams,(count($teams)/2));
        $home = $teams;
        for ($i=0; $i < count($home)+count($away)-1; $i++)
        {
            for ($j=0; $j<count($home); $j++)
            {
                $round[$i][$j]["Home"]=$home[$j];
                $round[$i][$j]["Away"]=$away[$j];
            }
            if(count($home)+count($away)-1 > 2)
            {
                $s = array_splice( $home, 1, 1 );
                $slice = array_shift( $s  );
                array_unshift($away,$slice );
                array_push( $home, array_pop($away ) );
            }
        }
        return $round;
    }
```

the output is

> Round: 1
>   peter  with    susan,
>   john   with    anna
>
> Round: 2
>   peter  with    john,
>   susan  with    anna etc....

Comment: So they must be paired differently the second round? It can't be random (where there's a chance of same pairs)?

Comment: @Qirel yes male with female only

Comment: Yes, but can Peter be paired with Susan the second (or third, or a later) round too, or is it only once?

Comment: @Qirel only once.

Comment: What should it do if it doesn't match with genders?

Comment: @Qirel  'hold'   eg. peter with hold

Comment: @Szmerd did you ever manage to solve this? I'm looking for a solution to the exact same problem 